# Why getDisplayValues() and then setValues() does not set values as they appear in the sheet (google apps script)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In 1 sheet and specific column I've got data like "thursday 2021-09-22". I use

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("some_name");
.getRange(1, 4, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("some_name").getLastRow(), 1).getDisplayValues();
```

At the end of the code I use setValues() (Same story, `sheet.getRange().setValues()`) on a different sheet. Yet somehow, in like 40% of cases the day name is missing, or even the YYYY-MM-dd order gets inverted. I don't understand how it's possible cause I'm not doing anything with those values in the code, it's just like copy paste and works in another code, but not this one. Does someone know what might be the case?

Comment: It may depend on your locale. So please share a copy of your spreadsheet so that you can reproduce the issue in your settings.

Comment: I can't really do that since I have private data there which I can't share :/

Comment: You can always create a sheet of dummy data that people can access and play with. By doing so, people will be more eager to help out. Sincerely yours!

Comment: Here is a "good" example of why sometimes the month and the day are reversed! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69296839/subquery-equivalent-in-google-sheets

Comment: Ok, the order is another problem, but still missing day name is a problem. Array that has values from getDisplayValues() is ok, but setValues() doesn't input them right, formatting isn't a problem as far as I can see. I can't reproduce it on another sheet cause it works there with the same data xd Maybe I'll share whole code if it helps, but I don't do anything with this data there