# SUBQUERY equivalent in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

Using a QUERY, I try to calculate the maximum number of pallets registered on the day with the most pallets registered during the month. This column would intitulate "Max day".

LINK of my SpreadSheet :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DkLmJUUFJgnlMD2u-PYcxmPlal-arwrsFNVQ0Q36T_w/edit?usp=sharing

I thought about something like this : `QUERY(Days!Ax:Ex;"select max(sum(D)) group by A";-1)`

But  it prints me an error.

So I imagine a sort of "Select" in a Select (sort of subquery) but I don't know if that exists or the way to go on.

If someone has an answer or another mean to reach my goal it could be very usefull.

Also I tried a PivotTable but I cannot summarize this column "Max day" (I'm also looking for this way).

Comment: You imported dates written as month / day / year in a spreadsheet configured in FR ... so October 1 will be interpreted as January 10, and all dates whose first value is greater than 12 will be interpreted as is like a string! Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

By this way, you will get the max value per month

```
=query(query(A3:E;"select C,sum(D),max(A) group by C ");"select Col3,max(Col2) group by Col3")
```

then you can look for which day ... the problem is that your dates are in Anglo-Saxon and your sheet in FR. Some value are considered as date, some as string! You probably need to align the dates and the locale.

### edit

I reconstructed all the dates in FR, all the formulas are under yellow cells https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11WegOTxespMKP5UDCtxoObk3wStl8MNQezE2e1k_XMk/copy

Comment: Hello Mike, that helps me a lot, I didn't expect that date formats would have an impact ; Your explanation is very clear and I thank you for the interest you have shown in my question

Comment: In your file, take a look at line 243, the date as interpreted by your spreadsheet configured as FR is February 10, and in column A it says it is October. It took me a while to get the real dates. The lesson is, when you have US dates, configure your spreadsheet in US before uploading data.

Comment: I think I just understood part of my mistake, indeed, the file I am working on is in US-en while the workbook I shared with you is in FR. I also forgot the fact that when I copy + paste values from one workbook to another, the format is not necessarily the same, which caused this reading "error" since the workbook was trying to read my US dates in FR. 

Thanks again for your help